# PDFsharp cannot read text from Crystal Reports CR23-encoded documents

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports, pdfsharp

We are using Crystal Reports, C# and PDFsharp to generate PDF documents by individual users. Crystal Reports is first used to create a single monolithic PDF document with all the users' entries, with each user's respective portion delineated by text "tags." Afterwards, a C# program generates individual PDFs from the monolith, by extracting its text with PDFsharp, searching for the tags, and then generating a PDF from each between-tag portion.

This process worked fine for many years, but starting with Crystal Reports Service Pack 23, the encoding of the generated PDFs is no longer readable by PDFsharp, and hence the tags cannot be found. (No such problem occurs when copying from these documents if they are rendered in Chrome or Firefox.)

Is there a setting that can be changed in Crystal Reports to restore the old encoding, or must we either modify PDFsharp or use a different PDF processing library?

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample PDF and indicate the text tags that are no longer readable?

Comment: They appear to be in compressed streams. I should write a utility to decompress them in the hopes it will reveal differences. I may be able to fix PDFSharp on my own.

Comment: Now that I have a utility to decode streams, I see that the document's Tj operator calls use text consisting of indexes instead of ASCII characters, and that's why our calls are returning gibberish. They're returning the indexes instead of the character codes.

Comment: in this situation the fonts must include a ToUnicode cmap otherwise the text extraction is not possible. Also PDFSharp must support ToUnicode cmaps for text extraction.

Comment: The fonts include ToUnicode CMaps. PDFSharp has the infrastructure for CMaps, but currently does not populate it. It is a work in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SP16-generated PDFs used WinAnsi encoding, but the SP23 ones use Unicode. SAP said there is no setting in Crystal Reports to force the encoding to WinAnsi.

Solving this problem required adding ToUnicode CMap-retrieval to PDFsharp and using the CMaps at runtime to map each CString text index to its corresponding Unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this answer but it was deleted. I can't figure out why, given that it addresses an explicit question: "or must we either modify PDFsharp **or use a different PDF processing library**?"
I have no financial interest in the suggested library! I'm not the developer of it. I only use it.
Perhaps whoever decided to delete, didn't bother to read the whole question.

---

Consider using a different library. I use the Quick PDF library (Foxit, formerly Debenu) to do PDF splitting by tag in Crystal exports. It works fine for pdfs exported from any version of Crystal, including the latest runtime.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen your answer.